# Android 4.4.2 LocationResult.hasResult(intent) gives Unmarshalling unknown type code

Tags: android, location, unmarshalling, parcel, fusedlocationproviderapi

In my service I have set the FusedLocation request location to send location to static BroadcastReceiver

```
public static class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    private LocationResult mLocationResult;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
      try {
        Log.d("Test", "has result = " + LocationResult.hasResult(intent));
        ...
```

In our crash reports we have many Anroid 4.4.2 users (but not all of them and not all the time....) where LocationResult.hasResult(intent); throws a

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@2ea0e34c:
>   Unmarshalling unknown type code 7274595 at offset 248 at
>   android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2080) at
>   android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314) at
>   android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249) at
>   android.os.Bundle.containsKey(Bundle.java:299) at
>   android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:4443) at
>   com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult.hasResult(Unknown
>   Source)

I don't have any 4.4.2 device and on the emulator I cannot reproduce/don't know how to reproduce or what causes this ?

Any one has already saw this ? Should I just try catch it ?

Comment: Seeing the  something similar in crash reports but havent figured out the root cause. Crash I am seeing is when trying to get the parcable extra but the rest looks identical. Will be doing some more investigating. Probably will catch the exception if investigating leads no where.

Comment: @Johny19 were you able to fix this crash?

Comment: nop.... I'm try catching it now because no one complained. must be some strange edge case scenario and also... f*ck 4.4.2 :)

Comment: @Johny19 I made a ticket on Android bugtracker. Let's see if somebody answers. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228612. Just started seeing this crash again a few days ago.